# MPLAB IDE- building an empty project

Tags: build, pic, mplab

I am trying to build an empty project on MPLAB using the device PIC18f452.
This is the error I am getting:

`Debug build of project  'C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\MyProject.mcp' started.
Language tool versions: MPASMWIN.exe v5.35, mplink.exe v4.35
Preprocessor symbol`__DEBUG' is defined.

### Thu May 09 20:03:42 2013

Make: The target "C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\18F452TMPO.o" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\New folder (2)\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\MPASM Suite\MPASMWIN.exe" /q /p18F452 "New folder (2)\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\MPASM Suite\Template\Object\18F452TMPO.ASM" /l"18F452TMPO.lst" /e"18F452TMPO.err" /o"18F452TMPO.o" /d__DEBUG=1
Make: The target "C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\MyProject.cof" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\New folder (2)\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\MPASM Suite\mplink.exe" "New folder (2)\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\MPASM Suite\LKR\18f452_g.lkr" "18F452TMPO.o" /u_DEBUG /z__MPLAB_BUILD=1 /z__MPLAB_DEBUG=1 /o"MyProject.cof" /M"MyProject.map" /W
MPLINK 4.35, Linker
Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Microchip Technology Inc.
Error - Error reading object file '18F452TMPO.o'
Errors    : 1

### Link step failed.

Debug build of project `C:\Users\Rabbiya\Desktop\MyProject.mcp' failed.
Language tool versions: MPASMWIN.exe v5.35, mplink.exe v4.35
Preprocessor symbol`__DEBUG' is defined.

### Thu May 09 20:03:43 2013

BUILD FAILED`

When i right-click and build the source file in the Project window , then it builds successfully.
What am I supposed to do? Seperately assemble all the .asm files in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you don't have **XC32** Compiler installed on your system. Instead, you can use MPLAB X.